# Difference between polymorphism and function overloading in c++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++. Can any one explain me on difference between polymorphism and function overloading using some examples or give me some links through which i can learn.

Comment: It is easier to explain what they have in common.  Nothing.  Overloading is simply a naming convenience.

Comment: Function overloading is one kind of Polymorphism.

Comment: @HansPassant: I think that's not a very convincing point. After all, they do have in common that they involve different functions of identical names, don't they? I can imagine this to be confusing for a beginner, although this particular question is way too broad, which is why I've close-voted it.

Comment: Polymorphism always implements the same operation on different but related data entities (Unless the programmer is being perverse). Function overloading can implement the same operation on related types, or, as with the << operator in the standard stream library, it can be used to implement totally different operations.

Answer (score 0):

overloading is creating a method with the same name with a different amount of parameters, or with parameters which are of another type.

polymorphism is about changing the functionality of a specific method across various types (which all have the same 'base-type').

Function overloading:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void DoThingies( int a, int b ) {}

    public void DoThingies( int a, int b, string x ) {}
}
```

Polymorphism:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract DoThingies();
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
    public override DoThingies()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

public class B : BaseClass
{
     public override DoThingies()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("B");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is another important concept of OOP. We can achieve polymorphism  using OOP classes.

**There are 2 concepts of polymorphism:**

**Overloading**: Function overloading is a feature where two or more functions can have the same name but different parameters. When a the function is called, it provide output based on the parameters. It happens at the compile time, that's why it is called Compile-Time polymorphism.

The following code may help you to understand.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int i) {
cout << " Here is int " << i << endl;
}
void print(double f) {
cout << " Here is float " << f << endl;
}
void print(char const *c) {
cout << " Here is char* " << c << endl;
}

int main() {
print(10);
print(10.10);
print("ten");
return 0;
}
```

It is also called static binding as static binding happens at the compile-time. We may also recognize this as the term of early binding.

**Overriding** : Override a method in base class by creating similar method in derived class. As it happens while the program runs, it is called Run-Time polymorphism.

The following code may help you to understand.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
   public:
    void print() {
        cout << "Base Function" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
   public:
    void print() {
        cout << "Derived Function" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived derived1;
    derived1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

It is also called dynamic binding as dynamic binding happens at the runtime. Another term of the feature is late binding.